# scala assign value to object

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following code:

```
 def getContentComponents: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
        contentComponentDTO.list().map(contentComponentsFuture =>
          contentComponentsFuture.foreach(contentComponentFuture =>

            contentComponentFuture.typeOf match {
              case 5 =>
                contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentText(contentComponentFuture.id.get).map(
                  text => contentComponentFuture.text = text.text
                )
            }
          )
            Ok(Json.toJson(contentComponentsFuture))
        )
```

and get this error message while assigning a value:

[image]

Is there a way to solve this issue?

I thought about creating a copy but that would mean that I have do lots of other stuff later. It would be much easier for me if I could reassign the value.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution ...

In model I have to define the Attributes as var

```
case class ContentComponentModel(
                              id: Option[Int] = None,
                              typeOf: Int,
                              name: String,
                              version: String,
                              reusable: Option[Boolean],
                              createdat: Date,
                              updatedat: Date,
                              deleted: Boolean,
                              processStepId: Int,
                              var text: Option[String],
```

Comment: Bad solution. Scala philosophy is rather immutability, so should better use `.copy` available on all case class

Comment: As you can read in many tutorial accross the Web, Scala immutable collections provided such operation (append) in the safe way.

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation first please http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible as `contentComponentFuture.text` is an immutable property so you cannot change its value like that.

The only way to "change" the values of the job object is to actually create a totally new instance and discard the old one. This is standard practice when dealing with immutable objects.

Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: what do you think about my solution just found a second bevore you answered, posted it as a answer as well

Comment: I would say it's a viable option, but as it's not standard practice I would avoid doing so. If it suits your application and you take care of that value well within your application you shouldn't have any problems.