# scala Returns Future[Unit] instead of Future[ContentComponentModel]

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following code:

```
  def getContentComponents: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
        val test = contentComponentDTO.list().map { contentComponentsFuture =>
          contentComponentsFuture.foreach(contentComponentFuture =>

            contentComponentFuture.typeOf match {
              case 1 =>
                println("blubb")
              case 5 =>
                contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentText(contentComponentFuture.id.get).map(
                  text => {
                    contentComponentFuture.text = text.text
                    println(text.text)
                    println(contentComponentFuture.text)
                  }
                )
            }
          )

        }

    Future.successful(Ok(Json.obj("contentComponents" -> test)))

  }
```

and I got this error message:

[image]

The .list() method should return a Future[ContentComponentModel]

`def list(): Future[Seq[ContentComponentModel]] = db.run {`

whats my mistake in this case?

thanks

Comment: Try to add the explicit type to the `val`

Comment: `val test: Future[Seq[ContentComponentModel]] = contentComponentDTO.list().map { ... }` says `Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type S_`

Comment: Which is right, as `case 1 => println(...)` is `Unit`, and `case 5` either `Future[Unit]` or `Unit`. Would really suggest to have a look at Scala tutorial.

Comment: I know that the return value isn't correct. That's what my original question was all about. I wanted to know a way to return my seq via json. As you can see, I needed to mutate every object within the seq (`.text = `text.text`) and then return the mutated seq

Comment: As said on the other question, you cannot and you should not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835422/scala-assign-value-to-object/45835523?noredirect=1#comment78633793_45835523

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala assign value to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835422/scala-assign-value-to-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contentComponentsFuture should be of type Seq[ContentComponentModel]. In this case You should move

```
Future.successful(Ok(Json.obj("contentComponents" -> test)))
```

just into the map expression (which is async) after loop.

It should looks something like:

```
def getContentComponents: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
val test = contentComponentDTO.list().map { contentComponents =>
  contentComponents.foreach(contentComponentFuture =>
    contentComponentFuture.typeOf match {
      case 1 =>
        println("blubb")
      case 5 =>
        contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentText(contentComponentFuture.id.get).map(
          text => {
            contentComponentFuture.text = text.text
            println(text.text)
            println(contentComponentFuture.text)
          }
        )
    }
  )
  Future.successful(Ok(Json.obj("contentComponents" -> contentComponents)))
}
```

}

Comment: Try deleting Action[AnyContent] because You dont need it. If it is not working try return "Future(Ok...." or even "Ok(Json.obj(.... )"