# How to solve Scala asynchronous behaviour

Tags: scala, playframework

In my backend controller function I have the following code:

```
  def getContentComponents = Action.async {
    contentComponentDTO.list().map { contentComponentsFuture =>
      contentComponentsFuture.foreach(contentComponentFuture =>
        contentComponentFuture.typeOf match {
          case 5 => contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentText(contentComponentFuture.id.get).map(text => {
            contentComponentFuture.text = text.text
            println(contentComponentFuture.text)
          })

        }
      )
      Ok(Json.toJson(contentComponentsFuture))
    }
  }
```

The problem is, that `OK()` is called before the stuff above is finished. Is there a smart way to wait until the `foreach` is finished?

thanks

That have been two differen questions with different problems! So thats the reason for two questions looking similar

Comment: that's far from being the first question on this function. I would highly recommend to first read Scala and Play tutorials before asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala Returns Future\[Unit\] instead of Future\[ContentComponentModel\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835922/scala-returns-futureunit-instead-of-futurecontentcomponentmodel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches that you can take, but before going to that let's recap what you are trying to do.

1. You have a list of items contentComponentsFuture, I am assuming retrieving from database, which is why you are getting a future.
2. Now your contentComponentsFuture is a mutable variable (which I strongly suggest not to use, stick to immutable data) has a text field which you need to update.
   Now all that code block before the Ok() will return a future as it is working on a future list. So the easiest solution is to do a map over the future and return the result. The map over a future is just a onComplete function which triggers once the future is resolved. So the code will look like:

   ```
   def getContentComponents = Action.async {
   val futureResult = contentComponentDTO.list().map { contentComponentsFuture =>
     contentComponentsFuture.map(contentComponentFuture =>
       contentComponentFuture.typeOf match {
         case 5 => contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentText(contentComponentFuture.id.get).map(text => {
           contentComponentFuture.text = text.text
           contentComponentFuture
         })
       }
     )
   }
       futureResult.map(result => {
   Future.sequence(result).map(t => Ok(Json.toJson(t))
   ```

   }))
       }

The other option will be to use scala asycn library: https://github.com/scala/scala-async
which gives a handy wrapper so that you do not need to map over future explicitly, the same code above with scala async library will look like below:

```
def getContentComponents = Action.async {
    Async.async {
    val result = Async.await(contentComponentDTO.list().map { contentComponentsFuture =>
      contentComponentsFuture.map(contentComponentFuture =>
        contentComponentFuture.typeOf match {
          case 5 => contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentText(contentComponentFuture.id.get).map(text => {
            contentComponentFuture.text = text.text
            contentComponentFuture
          })
        }
      )
    })

    Ok(Json.toJson(result))
  }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, when I try first solution, already tried as well I got this message:

Comment: `No Json serializer found for type Unit. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.`

Comment: updated the code, instead of println return the modified variable: contentComponentFuture
since println return unit, you are getting the error.

Comment: tried. but same result.

also tried this:  `Ok(Json.obj("test" -> result))` then I got type mismatch;
found Unit required: required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper

Comment: try now please updated the code again, foreach itself returns unit, I am so used to map that I did not notice you were using foreach to modify.

Comment: Okay now there is a different Message:

Comment: `No Json serializer found for type Seq[scala.concurrent.Future[models.ContentComponentModel]].`

Comment: Okay, sorry for the sloppy solution. There is another database call inside the map operation, so the final result has turned into a Future[Seq[Future]]
So we need to convert the Seq[Future] to Future[Seq]. Updated the code one more time, I am hoping you are understanding what is happening with all these futures. If not let me know, I will post a detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks for the correction. but there is something wrong ... I think with the parentheses. It would very kind if you will post a detailed version

Comment: ah I found the mistake. the last part should be:
`futureResult.flatMap(
    result => Future.sequence(result).map(
   t => Ok(Json.toJson(t))))}`